# How do I migrate my question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, closed-questions, migration

For this question:

[JDBC Connection Pool details on Glassfish](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534320/jdbc-connection-pool-details-on-glassfish),

can I just copy/past elsewhere, or should I flag and ask for it to be migrated?

What's the procedure?

To get a little bit meta about this question on meta, should the original question get migrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can flag it for moderator attention, and in the reason state that you want it migrated. (And the target site's moderators may decide to reject the migration.)

It would be quicker to simply copy your question over and delete this one.